The value of the two variables calculated in same way but can't match in pine script
I am trying to transfer the pine script to another programming language, so I need to figure out all the variables. Here is my code :
    // Define bar structure for Heikin Ashi method
    type HA
        float o = na
        float h = na
        float l = na
        float c = na
    // Function to calculate Heikin Ashi values
    ha(o, h, l, c) =>
        var HA x = HA.new()
        x.c := (o + h + l + c) / 4
        x.o := na(x.o[1]) ? (o + c) / 2 : (nz(x.o[1]) + nz(x.c[1])) / 2
        x.h := math.max(h, math.max(x.o, x.c))
        x.l := math.min(l, math.min(x.o, x.c))
        x
    // Base calculations, src and rsiLength are input value
    rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, rsiLength)
    
    // Simple neural network logic (linear combination with weighted aggregation)
    var float[] inputs = array.new_float(nnLength, na)
    for i = 0 to nnLength - 1
        array.set(inputs, i, rsi1[i])
    nnOutput = 0.0
    for i = 0 to nnLength - 1
        nnOutput := nnOutput + array.get(inputs, i) * (1 / nnLength)
        nnOutput
    
    
    // Calculate Heikin Ashi representation
    o = na(nnOutput[1]) ? nnOutput : nnOutput[1]
    h = math.max(nnOutput, nnOutput[1])
    l= math.min(nnOutput, nnOutput[1])
    c = nnOutput
    ha = ha(o, h, l, c)
    calculated_ha_o = na(ha.o[1]) ? (o + c) / 2 : (nz(ha.o[1]) + nz(ha.c[1])) / 2
    plot(calculated_ha_o, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Calculated ha.o")
    plot(ha.o, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="ha.o")

Based on the code I have provided, the calculated_ha_o is supposed to match ha.o because they are calculated in the same logic, but the outputs based on the plot on tradingview graph are greatly different, their values are close but plus minus 1 difference. Does historical references like [1] inside a function work differently than that outside a function? Can you clarify why they can't match and How I can find a variable similar to calculated_ha_o to verify the math logic of ha.o
Any answers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You cannot compare floating point values for exact equality. See Is floating point math broken? for an explanation of why.

@KenWhite  Sorry for the confusion. I didn't compare those two variables. I just plotted those two variables and found their values on the graph aren't even close. The max difference is almost 2. It is way more than the influence regarding float point math.
